# Aggregation last value and aggregation sum mdx mondrian

Tags: aggregate, mdx, cube, mondrian

I would like to write two mdx queries with mondrian to analyze the stock.
the first query is about exception last value aggregation and the second is about sum aggregation.
below is my table of facts.
Thank you.

my mdx :

with MEMBER [Measures].[STD LastValue]
AS ([Measures].[stock journalier],[Day].currentmember.lastchild) select [Measures].[STD LastValue] on columns from [stock analysis]

i want to know procedure to do that.

Comment: Can you please post the MDX that you have already tried?

Comment: @whytheq
with MEMBER [Measures].[LastValue]      
AS ([Measures].[stock journalier],[Day].currentmember.lastchild)
select [Measures].[LastValue] on columns 
from [stock analysis]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go up the hierarchy before applying LASTCHILD.

But also currentmember is related to the context of the SELECT clause.
Try adding months to the ROWS of the select so that currentmember has a context.

Comment: How to get columns from fact table to cube without use aggregation on mondrian?